# Gitlab CI - Start Nginx for E2E testing

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, e2e-testing

Summary: I just want to run a nginx reverse proxy inside gitlab-ci, which maps to containers that I start using docker-compose up, so that I can run E2E tests on my application automatically.

So, I have an application that has 3 services: 1 DB, 1 Node API, and 1 Nginx server, which is serving angular static files.

In production, these services sit behind a nginx reverse proxy.

I want to be able to run E2E tests using an environment very similar to production.
So I have created a base image to run my Continuous Integration tests, which looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Use edge packages
RUN sed -i -e 's/v[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]/edge/g' /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk upgrade --update-cache --available

RUN apk update
RUN apk add npm
RUN apk add docker
RUN apk add py-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install docker-compose
RUN apk add openrc --no-cache
RUN rc-update add docker boot
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install -g protractor

# chromium dependencies
RUN apk add openjdk8-jre-base
RUN apk add nss
RUN apk add chromium-chromedriver
RUN apk add chromium
RUN apk upgrade --no-cache --available
ENV CHROME_BIN /usr/bin/chromium-browser
# netcat to test for docker-compose up
RUN apk add netcat-openbsd 
# add netstat to get listening ports
RUN apk add net-tools

## Install nginx to run as reverse proxy
RUN apk add nginx
RUN rc-update add nginx boot
# Add nginx conf
COPY ./proxy.crt /etc/nginx/proxy.crt
COPY ./proxy.key /etc/nginx/proxy.key
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

My gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/ldso18-19/t2g2/base_ci:1.0
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  WEB_TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/ldso18-19/t2g2/web:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  API_TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/ldso18-19/t2g2/api:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  DB_TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/ldso18-19/t2g2/db:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  WEB_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/ldso18-19/t2g2/web:latest
  API_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/ldso18-19/t2g2/api:latest
  DB_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/ldso18-19/t2g2/db:latest

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com

web_integration_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - rc-status
    - nginx -t
    - /etc/init.d/nginx start
    - netstat -l
    - docker-compose pull
    - docker-compose up -d
    - cd web/e2e
    - sleep 10
    - netstat -l
    - protractor prod-conf.js
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # enable reverse proxy
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;    

    server {

        server_name localhost;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/proxy.crt; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/proxy.key; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";


        # Reverse Proxying (ineeve)
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://docker:4200;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass https://docker:8443/;
        }
    }
}
daemon off;
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/project_name/web:42-ci
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    depends_on:
      - api
  db:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/project_name/db:42-ci
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  api:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/project_name/api:42-ci
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
volumes:
  postgres:
```

The problem: when gitlab-ci runs I get the following error:

```
$ rc-status
Service `hwdrivers' needs non existent service `dev'
 * Caching service dependencies ... [ ok ]
Runlevel: sysinit
Dynamic Runlevel: hotplugged
Dynamic Runlevel: needed/wanted
Dynamic Runlevel: manual
$ nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
$ /etc/init.d/nginx start
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
 * ERROR: networking failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start nginx as networking would not start
```

Any help would be much appreciated because I have spent almost 10h trying different configurations.

Comment: Same thing here. I don't think the issue comes from your nginx conf. The issue might be the one with openrc not started at boot. I looked at the docker hub official nginx image and they start it this way `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` . Sounds Alpine completely rely on some kind of orchestrator to manage service availability. I commented this same issue about it https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/437. The op didn't have any answer on this issue...

Comment: the issue appears to me that it's not so easy to start nginx on raw gitlabci? why not run the nginx inside the container as well?

Comment: @UkuLoskit, that's what I'm trying right now. I decided to put the reverse proxy in a container, and it seems to be working